# (Snowflake) SQL Query for Handling Employee Periods and Roles

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

*Hi everyone, I am currently facing a challenge with writing an SQL query that involves handling employee periods and their roles. I have a situation where employees have multiple assignments with start and end dates, and I need to consolidate this data to get distinct periods and roles for each employee. I've tried a few approaches but haven't been able to achieve the desired output.*

**I have two tables: PERSON and TRACK, which track employee information and assignments respectively. Here's a simplified version of the data**

```
PERSON
PERSON_ID
77          

TRACK
TRACK_ID PERSON_ID  START_DATE  END_DATE    CURRENT_EMPLOYEE_FLAG JOB_TITLE
1        77         2021-08-06  2023-01-07  Y                     Account Executive
1        77         2023-01-07  2023-07-30  null                  null  
1        77         2023-08-01  null        Y                     Account Manager
```

**Desired Output:**

I want to generate a result that combines periods and roles, considering terminated periods, like this:

```
PERSON_ID   START_DATE  END_DATE    ROLE
28215       2021-08-06  2023-01-07  Account Executive
28215       2023-01-07  2023-07-30  Terminated
28215       2023-08-01  null        Account Manager
```

**Attempt:**
I've tried using CTEs and window functions, but I'm struggling to correctly handle terminated periods and role changes. Below is the query that I have thus far but I am stuck:

```
WITH Merged_table as(
SELECT t1.person_id,
      t2.effective_Start_date as periodstart,
      t2.effective_END_Date as periodend,
      Current_employee_flag,
      LAG(Current_employee_flag) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Person_ID ORDER BY t2.effective_Start_date) AS Prev_employee,
      paaf.ass_attribute6 as assignment_name
  FROM table1 t1
  left join table2 t2 on t1.person_id = t2.person_id 
       and t2.effective_start_date >= t1.effective_start_date and t2.effective_end_date <= t1.effective_end_date
  where t1.person_id = 77
)
,
Consolidated_Periods as(
    SELECT
        Person_ID,
        periodstart,
        LEAD(periodstart) OVER (PARTITION BY Person_ID ORDER BY periodstart) AS PeriodEnd,
        Current_employee_Flag,
        assignment_name
    FROM Merged_Table
)
,
GroupedRows AS (
    SELECT
        Person_ID,
        lead(periodstart) over (PARTITION BY Person_ID order by periodstart) AS  next_Start_date,
        lead(periodend) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID ORDER BY PERIODSTART) AS END_Date,
        assignment_name,
        Current_employee_flag
    FROM Consolidated_Periods
)
SELECT
    Person_ID,
    Start_date,
   END_Date,
    CASE
        WHEN MAX(Current_employee_flag) IS NULL THEN 'Terminated'
        ELSE MAX(assignment_name)
    END AS Role
FROM GroupedRows
GROUP BY Person_ID, TO_VARCHAR(Start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
ORDER BY Person_ID, Start_date;
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `where employees have multiple assignments`... but your sample data does not seemingly reflect this. Is that because your person table only stores the current assignment? If a person is terminated an no longer employed, are they removed from the Person table?

Comment: I made a mistake :( sorry about that. I went ahead and updated my question with the proper edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your current sample data, you are seemingly making this much more complicated than necessary. This is a solution based on your current sample data and desired output, which is simply using a `case expression`.

```
with person as (
 select 77 as person_id, 'Account Exec' as job_title union all
 select 66, 'Sales' union all
 select 55, 'HR'
), 
track as (
 select 77 as person_id, to_date('2021-08-06') as start_date, to_date('2023-01-07') as end_date, 'Y' as current_employee_flag union all
 select 77, to_date('2023-01-08'), to_date('2023-07-30'), null union all
 select 77, to_date('2023-08-01'), null, 'Y' union all
 select 66, to_date('2023-01-01'), null, 'Y' union all
 select 55, to_date('2022-04-15'), to_date('2022-10-31'), null
)
select 
 t.person_id, 
 t.start_date, 
 t.end_date, 
 case when t.current_employee_flag = 'Y' then p.job_title else 'Terminated' end as role
from track t
join person p
  on t.person_id = p.person_id
order by t.person_id, t.start_date
```

| PERSON_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE | ROLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 2022-04-15 | 2022-10-31 | Terminated |
| 66 | 2023-01-01 |  | Sales |
| 77 | 2021-08-06 | 2023-01-07 | Account Exec |
| 77 | 2023-01-08 | 2023-07-30 | Terminated |
| 77 | 2023-08-01 |  | Account Exec |

If your sample data are likely more complicated than what you currently have listed then please update the question. You mentioned that people could have multiple roles over time, but it's not clear if the person table keeps those roles and has a timestamp for each role.

**UPDATE**

Based on your recent update to your question, then you don't even need to join to the Person table. The query is simply this:

```
select 
 t.person_id, 
 t.start_date, 
 t.end_date, 
 case when t.current_employee_flag = 'Y' then t.job_title else 'Terminated' end as role
from track t
order by t.person_id, t.start_date
```

Or use `coalesce()` rather than a case expression...

```
select 
 t.person_id, 
 t.start_date, 
 t.end_date, 
 coalesce(t.job_title, 'Terminated') as role
from track t
order by t.person_id, t.start_date
```

Comment: Thanks for your response :) The problem is that this code would only work for a single person but we are trying to do this for MANY people. Should I update my question? I didnt want to make multiple entries in order to avoid confusion...

Comment: This answer works for n-nbr of people, as you can see with my sample data.

Comment: So sorry Isolated you are right, I think I may need to rethink how i frame this question. my apologies again and thank you for your help.